# Javascript Timer that works with business hours and weekends

Tags: javascript, timer

I'd like to write a a javascript function that when a button is pushed it starts a timer of 12 hours and then prompts some sort of alert. The tricky part of it is that it's for a business and that it must account for when the store is closed and/or on weekends.

**So essentially it would work like this:**

---

```
setTimer(function() {//do something},43200);

if (time == 5:30pm || day == Saturday || day == Sunday)
    while (time != 7:00am || day == Saturday || day == Sunday)
           pauseTimer;
```

---

I'm thinking something like this would work, although I open for any suggestions

Thanks in advance

Comment: No, this is not practicable in the way you outlined it, because such a while loop would freeze the browser. Do you actually need to “pause” the timer, or do you just need it to _end_ later? If the latter, then I’d rather _add_ the appropriate seconds for the “closed” hours of the business that fall into the period to the 12hrs that it starts with.

Comment: I don't have to actually pause the timer just writing an idea that I had for going about it. Thanks for the help